# auxiliary verb or bare infinitive?

Tags: modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs, perfect-constructions, bare-infinitives

*"She might have been waiting for us"*

‘Have been waiting’ forms the present perfect progressive tense

‘might’ is a modal verb

The verb that follows modal verbs is suppose to be a bare infinitive but how can that be here?
To form a verb tense you need helping verbs so the words ‘have been’ are suppose to be helping verbs
So which is it?
Is ‘have’ a helping verb or a bare infinitive?

Comment: I don't know why you think that a verb tense requires a 'helping' verb. It doesn't. Here, perfect "have" is a plain (infinitive) form and "been" is progressive, "Might" is a tensed form and "waiting" is a lexical verb. I strongly advise dropping the term 'helping verb'. It's nonsense.

Comment: I’m sorry. I didn’t know. What should they be called then?

Comment: If "helping verb" is another term for an auxiliary verb then yes, "have" and "been" are both auxiliaries here, as BillJ correctly says in his answer.  You state that "have been waiting" is present perfect progressive.  It can be.  But not necessarily.  In "(to) have been waiting", "have" is a bare infinitive.

Comment: What would that make “been waiting” in your example then?

Comment: @somerandomgirl "Have" can be either present tense (as in "I have") or infinitive (as in "to have", or bare as in "I can have", "I will have", "I might have").  Similarly, "have swum" can be present perfect, or it can be a perfect infinitive, as in "to have swum".  And "have been waiting" can be present perfect progressive, or it can be infinitive perfect progressive.  In "might have been waiting", "have been waiting" is perfect progressive, but it is non-finite - it isn't present tense.  (You can tell because "she might have been waiting" also uses "have", not "has"!).

Comment: I've added an edit to my answer to deal with the statement in the OP's question:  "Have been waiting’ forms the **present** perfect progressive tense".

Comment: I don’t understand when you say In "might have been waiting", "have been waiting" is perfect progressive, but it is non-finite - it isn't present tense.

Comment: You correctly stated that "have been waiting" is (sometimes) the present perfect progressive, but you seemed to imply that it was therefore present perfect progressive in "might have been waiting".  It isn't, because the "have" in "might have been waiting" is non-finite - it is untensed (so can't be present tense).  In "I have been waiting", "have" is tensed (and is part of the *present* perfect progressive), as shown by the fact that "has" is used in "she has been waiting".  By contrast, in "she might have been waiting", "have" is untensed (and therefore can't be present perfect progressive).

Comment: Roughly speaking, "finite" = "tensed" = subject to inflection for person/tense/number, whereas "non-finite" = "non-tensed" = either an infinitive or a participle.  In "I have waited", "have waited" is present perfect, whereas in "I want to have waited", "(to) have waited" is a perfect infinitive (so it's still perfect, but it's non-finite).  Similarly, in "I might have waited", "have waited" is a perfect infinitive (perfect, but non-finite).

Comment: @somerandomgirl The point is that in "might have been waiting", "have been waiting" is the perfect progressive tense, but it's **not** the present perfect because "have" is in the plain (infinitive) form so there is no compound tense, thus no present perfect tense. See the edit in my answer.

Comment: In one place, it says that the modal auxiliary verbs are considered finite verbs because they are the first verbs in their verb chains. So does that mean that a modal verb can be a main verb?

Comment: Yeah, "might" is finite. (In fact, it's always finite because modals have no infinitives nor participles - they lack non-finite forms.) So, in "I might have been waiting", the modal "might" is a finite verb. But, by contrast, the verb "have" isn't a finite verb in that construction, which is why it's not an instance of present perfect progressive. If by "main verb" you mean a non-auxiliary then I can't think of a case where a modal is a main verb.

Comment: "*Is ‘have’ a helping verb or a bare infinitive?*" - Both.  It's an auxiliary verb, and it's also a bare infinitive (in your example).

Comment: In “She might have been waiting for us” BillJ said that the word “waiting” is the main verb but what about the word “might” in this sentence?

Comment: In that sentence, "might" is finite and is a modal auxiliary.  "Have" is non-finite (a bare infinitive) and is also an auxiliary.  "Been" is non-finite (a participle) and is also an auxiliary.  "Waiting" is the main verb or lexical verb - the verb being governed by the chain of three prior auxiliary verbs (might, have, been).

Comment: So does that mean that the main verb and the finite verb are two different things?

Comment: @somerandomgirl Correct. The main verb and the finite verb are different things.  Sometimes they are the same verb, e.g. "see" in "I see". But wherever you have one or more auxiliaries, the finite verb (if any) is the first one of the auxiliaries (e.g. "have"in "I have seen", but sometimes, none are finite, e.g. "to have seen"), while the main verb comes last. See https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/main-verb https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-classification-main.htm  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/main-verb https://www.grammarly.com/blog/main-verb/

Comment: How did you guys learn everything you know because I wish I knew everything like you guys but instead I’m here bothering people

Comment: @somerandomgirl Hold on! I didn't say that "waiting" is the 'main verb'; I said it is a lexical verb (as opposed to an auxiliary verb). I never use the term 'main verb' because it is meaningless. Every clause has a verb, so in theory every clause has a main verb. In your example "might" is a 'main verb' in the clause " She might have been waiting for us", and "have" is a 'main verb' in the clause "have been waiting for us", and "been" is a 'main verb' in the clause "been waiting for us" and so on. Which is why I recommend dropping the term 'main verb'.

Comment: I’m sorry. I thought the words lexical verb and main verb meant the same thing. How are those clauses? I thought a clause was something that had both a subject and a verb

Comment: rjpond said that main verbs and  finite verbs are two different things and that the word “might” was an finite verb but you say that the word “might” is a main verb so who is right?

Comment: Clauses do have subjects, but in the case of non-finite clauses like "have been waiting for us" there is no overt subject. But in a sense we _understand_ them as having subjects.  For example, in "have been waiting for us", we think of "she" as the understood subject. May I suggest that you obtain a good up-to-date grammar textbook.

Comment: I also interpret "main verb" as meaning the same as "lexical verb", but it seems the term "main verb" can be understood in two different ways (whereas "lexical verb" is unambiguous).  The only definition of "main verb" in the Cambridge online dictionary is that it's a lexical verb, though. / You're not bothering us, but if you have any further follow-on questions, consider asking them as new questions, as the discussion in the  comments is getting too long.

Comment: It would be tricky to explain in comments the difference between the 'dependent-auxiliary' analysis, where the core auxiliaries are contrasted with main (lexical) verbs, and the much better and widely-adopted 'catenative-auxiliary' analysis, where there is one verb per clause.

Comment: @somerandomgirl I said that "might" wasn't the main verb because I was interpreting the term "main verb" to mean the lexical verb.  "Might" is always an auxiliary and never lexical.  Modal verbs are non-lexical.  Modal verbs are always finite (they lack non-finite forms - they have neither infinitives nor participles in standard English), so "might" is finite.

Answer (score 2):

> *She might have been waiting for us.*

Here, perfect "have" is a plain (infinitive) form.

"Have" is the perfect auxiliary and "been" is the progressive auxiliary.

The modal "might" is a tensed form and "waiting" is a lexical verb.

I strongly recommend dropping the term 'helping verb'. It's nonsense

Edit:

The perfect can combine with the preterite ("She had been waiting") and present tense ("She has been waiting"), where it is a compound tense. But it can also occur in clauses without inflectional tense, as in your example, where "have" is in the plain form, so there is no compound tense.